# I was trying to implement datatables in my Mkdocs material theme. But adding the custome code for datatables doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, mkdocs

Trying to get datatable into my mkdocs material theme. I tried different ways but it does not work consistently, sometimes work after page-referesh.

**mkdocs.yml**

```
extra_css:
  - extra.css
  - https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

extra_javascript:
  - https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
  - https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
  - scripts/site.js
```

**scripts/site.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('table.display').DataTable();
   } );
```

**table**

```
<table id="" class="display" style="width:100%">

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: The problem is with `scripts/site.js` and with the `id` used in the table. The value `'table.display'` in the JavaScript needs to match the `<table id="">` value.

If we set them both to something like `myTable`, then this should be fixed.

---

### Solution:

Markdown file:

```markdown
## Do data tables work?

<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Offices</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Tiger Nixon</td><td>Edinburgh</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Garrett Winters</td><td>Tokyo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ashton Cox</td><td>San Francisco</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cedric Kelly</td><td>Edinburgh</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Airi Satou</td><td>Tokyo</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`scripts/site.js` changed:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

Basically the same `mkdocs.yml` from above:

```yaml
extra_css:
  - https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

extra_javascript:
  - https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js
  - https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
  - scripts/site.js
```

Then it should work:

[image: A rendered version of data tables embedded in mkdocs.]

---

Thanks for asking this question: I was trying to do exactly what this question proposed and found both this StackOverflow thread and an issue ([#2056](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/2056)) listed in the mkdocs-material GitHub repository.

---

### Caveats

Data tables may not work properly with dark/light themes. Here I used the dark slate theme:

[image: Dark theme version of the site, the data table is completely unreadable.]

Comment: The page https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multiple_tables.html claims that the ´table.display' should work for entire classes of tables, not just specific ones, which would be convenient. Any idea why it doesn´t work and needs specific table-ids per table?

Comment: @HolgerHoefling that should be a separate question.

Comment: @AlexanderHayes: I thought here would be better as this was part of the original question. While not explicitly mentioned - this is where his script example is from.

Comment: Also this would not work for ajax delivered data https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html because you basically need more than one `script/site.js` to achieve that function I would think for each page using this table function. The data endpoint is why I would want to use datatables.js in the 1st place.